# Not able to install IIRF on Windows Server 2012 / IIS8

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012, iis-8, iirf

Not able to install iirf on Windows Server 2012. I used this msi file from codeplex: "Iirf2.1-x64"
http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=iirf&DownloadId=261341&FileTime=129654893866170000&Build=21018

Getting below error, couldn't find much help on Google or SO so far!

> Setup for Ionic's ISAPI Rewrite Filter 2.1 ended prematurely

Anyone experienced or solved this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You install IIRF by going to the IIS MMC snap-in and either at server level (for all websites) or on each website, you choose the ISAPI filters and click add, then just look for the DLL, click OK, restart IIS and you are done, no need to use the MSI. For IIS8 you need a version that's not available at the IIRF CodePlex project official site. I have been given a new version revision that works in IIS8+, this is version IIRF-2.1.2.4-x64 and I have made it available on my website (http://www.nelsonpires.com/web-development/ionics-isapi-rewrite-filter-aka-iirf-for-iis8/) for anyone to download and use. I have tested it and confirm it works great on IIS8.5. Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Wow! That really works!! Thanks a ton for reaching out to the authors and contributing to this. Although I've rewritten all the rules in URL Rewrite Module 2.0- this will come very much handy next time.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on the other related question here: [IIRF on IIS8 / Window Server 2012 Throwing w3wp.exe Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674567/iirf-on-iis8-window-server-2012-throwing-w3wp-exe-exceptions/31232352) - there's a fix for it.